# Blue border around Chosen select dropdown?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-chosen

I'm using [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) to style a drop down, but I can't seem to figure out how to eliminate a blue border/shadow after making a selection. I've tried `*:focus { outline: 0 !important; }` and these:

`#modelDropDown_chosen {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}`

`#modelDropDown {
    outline-width: 0;
    outline: 0;
}`

`.chosen-container-active {
    outline-width: 0;
    outline: 0 !important;
}`

and lots of other similar approaches but I just don't think I'm targeting the right component.

[Here is a link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLLuw.jpg) to an image of what I'm talking about. Any ideas/suggestions would be much appreciated!

EDIT: This only happens AFTER a selection has been made and stops if you click outside the drop down

Comment: What browser are you testing this on ?

Comment: I'm working primarily in Chrome but Safari seems to have it as well (Mac)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this should work:

```
.chosen-container-active .chosen-single {
   border: 1px solid #AAA;
   box-shadow: 0 0 3px #FFF inset, 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

Comment: that was a real bitch to find in Firebug :) the border disappears wherever you click in the entire window...

Comment: @Spencer delete what's inside `.chosen-container-active .chosen-single` scope. It should work

Comment: @Spencer do you have jsfiddle or some preview then?

Comment: try adding `!important` just before `;` just to test it. @MDeSchaepmeester I'm a huge fan of Chrome's Web Inspector :)

Comment: @pawel SO CLOSE! I added !important and now it looks like [this](http://imgur.com/lKqzAOl) instead of [this](http://imgur.com/NrfRqhX) so I think now it's just a matter of matching the border style. Thank you!!! And yep... Web Inspector is fantastic haha

Comment: Okey, so it should be `border: 1px solid #AAA;` instead of `border: none` in my previous answer. You could try with just `border-color: #AAA;` (see my edit)

Comment: @pawel I've been playing around with it but that updated code doesn't seem to be doing it. I also realized that by setting it equal to none, the border on the top of the drop down disappears when you open it so it actually looks pretty funky. Adding your revised code doesn't seem to do anything :/

Comment: Just did that and I can live with the results haha Now it looks like it should but it has a little shadow effect going on... The blue is what was killing me though, so thank you so much!

Comment: Here are [before](http://imgur.com/qaPwkSq) and [after](http://imgur.com/IpAKx74) pics for what it looks like before/after clicking elsewhere on the page

Comment: You could add `box-shadow: 0 0 3px #FFF inset, 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);` to disable that shadow effect (with `!important` I guess). Anyway, you should be able to do it without `!important`. Are you sure you include those CSS rules AFTER you include Choosen CSS?

Comment: Just checked and I am including my custom CSS AFTER chosen. Would that have made a difference? And there goes the shadow!!! You are the man haha

Comment: Well, then you shouldn't require !important. But, well, must be something else going on then ;)

Comment: @pawel I was looking at the wrong file -_- I've been looking at my screen for too long haha It was included before chosen. Anyways, thank you for your help!!!